# Java Android Studio + NodeJS Server Websocket connected but no message sent

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, websocket

I have a websocket server file called `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const port = 1234;
const server = http.createServer(express);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
})

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
    console.log("connected");

    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            if(client !== ws && client.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(data.toString());
                console.log(client.id + " => " + data.toString());
            }
        })
    })
})
```

In java i wanted to connect to the websocket with `initiateWebSocket()` function

```
private void instantiateWebSocket() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(WEBSOCKET_URL).build();
    SocketListener socketListener = new SocketListener(this);
    webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, socketListener);
}

public class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

    public MainActivity activity;
    public SocketListener (MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);

        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(activity, "Connection starts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
        webSocket.send("Hello..."); // send message here Hello
    }
}
```

So I wanted to send the word "**Hello...**" when the connection is connected to the websocket.

On my `server.js`, it showed `connected`, which means ws.on("connection") is executed...

But the weird part is ws.on("message") is not executed and **Hello...** is not received

Also note that I didn't received any errors, everything is working fine, only **Hello...** is not received.

Any advice? Thank you.